# How do you flog a fornicator?

Tags: zina, hudud

People who commit unlawful sexual intercourse are supposed to be flogged/whipped. Is this to be done as hard as humanely possible or really soft? Is it also supposed to be done in private or public?

Comment: Still looking for answers on the comments I posted to UmH’s answer please post an answer if you have any.

Answer (score 1):

For a normal healthy person, the strike should be of medium intensity, neither too soft so as to be ineffective, nor too hard so as to wound or kill. The whip should neither be totally worn nor new. The executor should not raise their hand so high as as to uncover the whiteness of their armpits. A single part of the body should not be hit repeatedly rather the strikes should be distributed. Soft parts of the body should be avoided, like the face and private parts. The punishment should be witnessed by a group of people as its purpose is deterrence.

> الزانية والزاني فاجلدوا كل واحد منهما مائة جلدة و**لا تأخذكم بهما رأفة في دين الله** إن كنتم تؤمنون بالله واليوم الآخر **وليشهد عذابهما طائفة من المؤمنين**
>
> The [unmarried] woman or [unmarried] man found guilty of sexual intercourse - lash each one of them with a hundred lashes, and **do not be taken by pity for them in the religion of Allah**, if you should believe in Allah and the Last Day. And **let a group of the believers witness their punishment**.
>
> <sup>— [Quran 24:2](http://quran.com/24/2)</sup>

References: [Muwatta Malik](http://sunnah.com/urn/415850), [Tafsir al-Qurtubi](https://quran.ksu.edu.sa/tafseer/qortobi/sura24-aya2.html#qortobi)

Comment: Right thank you. But does the flogging have to be done in public or private because in public it may cause heat on the media people wouldn’t want to convert to Islam or people with weak faith may be impacted

Comment: Is there no alternative to punishment because it can deter newcomers to Islam.